# How to break Singleton?

Tags: java

How to break singleton class in java?
Singleton Pattern ensures a class has only one instance and provides a global point of access to it.

The default constructor of the class is made private, which prevents the direct instantiation of the object by other classes.

A static modifier is applied to the instance method that returns the object as it then makes this method a class level method that can be accessed without creating an object

**EDIT:**

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton singleInstance;

    private Singleton() {
        System.out.println("Singleton Constructor Running...");
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() { 
        if (singleInstance == null) { 
            synchronized (Singleton.class) { 
            if (singleInstance == null) { 
                    singleInstance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        } 
        return singleInstance; 
    }
}
```

To Break Singleton Using Reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class BreakSingletonUsingReflection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton instanceOne = Singleton.getInstance();
        Singleton instanceTwo = null;
        try {
            Constructor[] constructors = Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
            for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
                //Below code will destroy the singleton pattern
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                instanceTwo = (Singleton) constructor.newInstance();
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(instanceOne.hashCode());
        System.out.println(instanceTwo.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break"?

Comment: What if it's implemented with `enum` instead?

Comment: public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (singleInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (singleInstance == null) {
                    singleInstance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return singleInstance;
    }

Comment: This smells like [an XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242) What end goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: to create a single object for database class

Comment: Using reflection an instance could be obtained, even if the constructor is private

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to end up with two instances of a Singleton? If so please state that in your question.

Comment: "to create a single object for database class" - soooo the intention is to actually figure out how to create a singleton which you CANNOT break?

Answer (score 2):

**1.**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;


    public class ReflectionSingletonTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EagerInitializedSingleton instanceOne = EagerInitializedSingleton.getInstance();
            EagerInitializedSingleton instanceTwo = null;
            try {
                Constructor[] constructors = EagerInitializedSingleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
                for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
                    //Below code will destroy the singleton pattern
                    constructor.setAccessible(true);
                    instanceTwo = (EagerInitializedSingleton) constructor.newInstance();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(instanceOne.hashCode());
            System.out.println(instanceTwo.hashCode());
        }

    }
```

***OR***

**2.**

**Singleton class:**

```
package com.singleton.securitymgr;

public class Singleton {

    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
        System.out.println("Singleton Constructor Running...");
    }

    public static final Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
package com.singleton.securitymgr;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();

        Class clazz = Singleton.class;

        Constructor cons = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
        cons.setAccessible(true);

        Singleton s2 = (Singleton) cons.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The singleton will only work per classLoader.  To break it, use multiple classLoaders

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to Serialize the Object store it in a file and Deserialize it to get a new Object.